# Gtk# + MonoDevelop: How to pop-up a custom widget on button click

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

I am new to Gtk# and Monodevelop. So please forgive the basic-ness of this question. But I am trying to do something really simple - and I can't seem to do it. Not sure if it matters, but I am developing on Linux

I have a MainWindow which has a button. When I click on this button, I want a custom widget to pop-up

I created a custom widget as a separate project, compile it as a .dll and refer it in the main project

In the main project, I have defined a call-back for button click - loadCustomWidget() 
However, the code below does not show the custom-widget on screen

```
public partial class CustomWidget : Gtk.Bin ; // in the other project

protected void loadCustomWidget() {
  Console.WriteLine(" show custom widget ") ;
  wg = new CustomWidget() ;
  wg.Show() ;
}
```

The WriteLine() is printed. So I know the call-back is being called. But why isn't the widget showing on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the widget into a container, for example add it to your main window.

Comment: Thanks Michael ... I continued trying different things after I posted. No strategy, just hit and trial. And I guess I eventually stumbled upon what you are suggesting - using containers. But thanks anyway for replying. My question would have come across as so,so basic to someone who develops MonoDevelop